# rpy2 fails to execute some R code in Jupyter Notebook: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, r-package, rpy2

I want to use R and Python in the same Jupyter notebook using the package `rpy2`. R works but I have an error when trying to load some R packages even though they are already installed in the environment I am using:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Then checking the installed packages with:

```
%%R
print(installed.packages())
```

That confirms that the packages `apTreeshape` and `geiger` that I want to use are installed:

```
                  Package             LibPath                                  
ape               "ape"               "C:/Users/pveron/anaconda3/Lib/R/library"
apTreeshape       "apTreeshape"       "C:/Users/pveron/anaconda3/Lib/R/library"
...
geiger            "geiger"            "C:/Users/pveron/anaconda3/Lib/R/library"
```

But then when I want to load them:

```
%%R
library(apTreeshape)
```

I have the following error message:

```
**RInterpreterError:** Failed to parse and evaluate line 'library(apTreeshape)\n'.
R error message: "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 158: invalid continuation byte"
```

I have the same error for multiple packages but not all of them.

(I am using Anaconda3 distribution with `Python 3.9.13`, `R 3.6.1` and the package `rpy2 3.5.7`).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: mixing 2 languages in the same code.  needs to point to two different interpreters from a computational perspective and the user needs two languages from a human perspective. Nevertheless an interesting concept... but why ?

Comment: @D.L this is very useful to take benefit of several programming languages, here R provides very useful packages for scientific computations, which are reviewed, published and updated !

Comment: Which platform are you on, Windows? Your R version is somewhat old. Have you tried updating?